# How to hide a slice of my amcharts3 pie chart at page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, amcharts

In the amcharts pie chart below i want it to load by default with Lithuania hidden.

I browsed a lot through amcharts documentation but couldn't find a valid example that would solve my problem. However, i did find a method called 
`hideSlice()` which would take an index as an argument and hide that slice i guess according to the documentation but if i pass `0` or `'0'` it would throw an error.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "startDuration": 0,
  "theme": "none",
  "addClassNames": true,
  "legend": {
    "position": "right",
    "marginRight": 100,
    "autoMargins": false
  },
  "innerRadius": "30%",
  "defs": {
    "filter": [{
      "id": "shadow",
      "width": "200%",
      "height": "200%",
      "feOffset": {
        "result": "offOut",
        "in": "SourceAlpha",
        "dx": 0,
        "dy": 0
      },
      "feGaussianBlur": {
        "result": "blurOut",
        "in": "offOut",
        "stdDeviation": 5
      },
      "feBlend": {
        "in": "SourceGraphic",
        "in2": "blurOut",
        "mode": "normal"
      }
    }]
  },
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "Lithuania",
    "litres": 501.9
  }, {
    "country": "Czech Republic",
    "litres": 301.9
  }, {
    "country": "Ireland",
    "litres": 201.1
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "litres": 165.8
  }, {
    "country": "Australia",
    "litres": 139.9
  }, {
    "country": "Austria",
    "litres": 128.3
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "litres": 99
  }, {
    "country": "Belgium",
    "litres": 60
  }, {
    "country": "The Netherlands",
    "litres": 50
  }],
  "valueField": "litres",
  "titleField": "country",
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});

chart.addListener("init", handleInit);

chart.addListener("rollOverSlice", function(e) {
  handleRollOver(e);
});

function handleInit() {
  chart.legend.addListener("rollOverItem", handleRollOver);
}

function handleRollOver(e) {
  var wedge = e.dataItem.wedge.node;
  wedge.parentNode.appendChild(wedge);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.amcharts-pie-slice {
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 #000;
}

.amcharts-pie-slice:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  filter: url(#shadow);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're likely calling `hideSlice` before the chart has finished initializing; `makeChart` is asynchronous, so calling methods on the chart right after the `makeChart` call is not guaranteed to work. In the same token, adding a listener on `init` outside of `makeChart` is also not a good idea for the same reason as `init` might resolve before your listener is attached.

Move the `hideSlice` call in your `init` listener:

```
handleInit() {
  // ...
  chart.hideSlice(0);
}
```

To ensure that `handleInit` is always called, define your listener inside your `makeChart` config:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  listeners: [{
    event: "init",
    method: handleinit
  }]
});
```

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "startDuration": 0,
  "theme": "none",
  "addClassNames": true,
  "legend": {
    "position": "right",
    "marginRight": 100,
    "autoMargins": false
  },
  "innerRadius": "30%",
  "defs": {
    "filter": [{
      "id": "shadow",
      "width": "200%",
      "height": "200%",
      "feOffset": {
        "result": "offOut",
        "in": "SourceAlpha",
        "dx": 0,
        "dy": 0
      },
      "feGaussianBlur": {
        "result": "blurOut",
        "in": "offOut",
        "stdDeviation": 5
      },
      "feBlend": {
        "in": "SourceGraphic",
        "in2": "blurOut",
        "mode": "normal"
      }
    }]
  },
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "Lithuania",
    "litres": 501.9
  }, {
    "country": "Czech Republic",
    "litres": 301.9
  }, {
    "country": "Ireland",
    "litres": 201.1
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "litres": 165.8
  }, {
    "country": "Australia",
    "litres": 139.9
  }, {
    "country": "Austria",
    "litres": 128.3
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "litres": 99
  }, {
    "country": "Belgium",
    "litres": 60
  }, {
    "country": "The Netherlands",
    "litres": 50
  }],
  "valueField": "litres",
  "titleField": "country",
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "init",
    "method": handleInit
  }]
});


chart.addListener("rollOverSlice", function(e) {
  handleRollOver(e);
});

function handleInit() {
  chart.legend.addListener("rollOverItem", handleRollOver);
  chart.hideSlice(0);
}

function handleRollOver(e) {
  var wedge = e.dataItem.wedge.node;
  wedge.parentNode.appendChild(wedge);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.amcharts-pie-slice {
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 #000;
}

.amcharts-pie-slice:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  filter: url(#shadow);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```